# How to connect google drive folder to google colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Need to call data folder but how to do it in colab. I tried it on spyder but not able to do in colab, already mounted google drive.

```
  import torch

  import cv2
  from data import BaseTransform, VOC_CLASSES as labelmap
  from ssd import build_ssd
  import imageio
```

[Image of google drive in collab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qc9t.png)

It will be better if I able to interect with whole Windows 1 folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to google colab using

```
from google.colab import drive
  import os
  drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

To call you can copy the path. You can get the path of the folder by right click --> copy path. You can use that path for reading/writing the files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I got the answer
I just did

```
cd /content/drive/Mypath
```