# How to save the predictions images result of YOLOV4 and YOLOV5 Object detection in image format in any folder?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo

I am new about YOLO Algorithms, I trained my datasets, how can I save those images who detected in prediction part in format image in a folder, after detecting?(yolov4 and yolov5- Googlecolab)

Answer (score 0):

You got `x,y,w,h and confidence` for detected objects. Use these results and crop detected objects from original images. Run prediction phase on test data, if `confidence` is bigger than a threshold save input image in a directory in your google drive(connect your google drive to google colab account. Check these  links: [Colaboratory: Can I access to my Google drive folder and file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744131/colaboratory-can-i-access-to-my-google-drive-folder-and-file), [How to connect google drive folder to google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650150/how-to-connect-google-drive-folder-to-google-colab) and [Is there a way to connect google colab to my google drive for good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754371/is-there-a-way-to-connect-google-colab-to-my-google-drive-for-good)).

[YOLO object detection with OpenCV](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, those links were very useful. I tried some codes but it was not working properly to save output image. Can you help please? How to save images which are detected in prediction phase in a directory in my google drive or any other folder in yolov4 and yolov5?

Comment: Yolov4 or Yolov5 is not a great matter. Did you check last link? It was not useful? and why?

Comment: yes. I did. but i can not save the results in my google drive . I mean after detecting, how should I save it. I know with below code I can copy , but is there any other way to save?

Comment: !./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg /mydrive/YOLOV4/training/yolov4-custom_best.weights /mydrive/images/Pic 1.jpg -thresh 0.3 
..........................................
imShow('predictions.jpg')
..........................................
import shutil
..........................................
drive_path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/YOLOV4/'
............................................
shutil.copy2('predictions.jpg', drive_path+'Pic 1.jpg')

Comment: **Darknet** has an api `darknet help`. you could call it in python and give it a list of images and you receive a text file that has location on objects in it.

Comment: Also, you could run **opencv dnn module** in `python` or `C++` for detecting objects.